# How can I read a json column from postgresql into java?

Tags: java, json, postgresql

This postgresql query

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(c))) FROM contacts c;
```

brings back a single column of type json. Here is the working query in pgadmin...
[image]

I would like to execute this same query from my Java server, which uses Jackson. What type should I read the response into? I have tried receiving the response as a PGobject variable, but after querying, I see that the variable is null.

I have also tried receiving the response into a String, but this throws the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.postgresql.util.PGobject is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Comment: Cast it to string using `::text`, i.e. `SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(c)))::text FROM contacts c` then retrieve using `stmt.getString(1)` and parse the string normally using Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

If the result is a json (or jsonb) you can use `ResultSet.getString()` to read it. Then pass that Jackson's ObjectMapper to convert it to something else.

Btw: you can simplify your aggregation to:

```
select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(c)) 
from FROM contacts c;
```

Comment: hmm. If I try to receive the result into a variable of type ResultSet, I get this error. java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to class java.sql.ResultSet (org.postgresql.util.PGobject is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.sql.ResultSet is in module java.sql of loader 'platform')

Comment: that is something completely different